# Best approach to read, optimize (polygon crunch) and display 3D model in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, polygon

I'm creating a tool that converts hi-poly meshes to low-poly meshes and I have some best practice questions on how I want to approach some of the problems.

I have some experience with C++ and DirectX but I prefer to use C#/WPF to create this tool, I'm also hoping that C# has some rich libraries for opening, displaying and saving 3d models. This brings me to my first question:

**Best approach for reading, viewing and saving 3d models**

To display 3D models in my WPF application, I'm thinking about using the Helix 3D toolkit.
To read vertex data from my 3D models I'm going to write my own .OBJ reader because I'll have to optimize the vertices and write out everything

**Best approach for optimizing the 3d model**

For optimization things will get tricky, especially when dealing with tons of vertices and tons of changes. Guess I'll keep it simple at the start and try to detect if an edge is on the same slope as adjacent edges and then I'll remove that redundant edge and retriangulate everything.

In later stages I also want to create LODs to simplify the model by doing the opposite of what a turbosmooth modifier does in Max (inverse interpolation). I have no real clue how to start on this right now but I'll look around online and experiment a little.

And at last I have to save the model, and make sure everything still works.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing 3D objects you can also consider the [Ab3d.PowerToys](http://www.ab4d.com/PowerToys.aspx) library - it is not free, but greatly simplifies work with WPF 3D and also comes with many samples.

OBJ file is good because it is very commonly used and has very simple structure that is easy to read and write to. But it does not support object hierarchies, transformations, animations, bones, etc. If you will need any of those, than you will need to use some other data format.

I do not have any experience in optimizing hi-poly meshes, so I cannot give you any advice here. Here I can only say that you may also consider combining the meshes with the same material into one mesh - this can reduce the number of draw calls and also improve performance.

My main advice is on how to write your code to make it perform better in WPF 3D. Because you will need to check and compare many vertices, you need to avoid getting data from the MeshGeometry3D.Positions and MeshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices collections - accessing a single value from those collections is very slow (you may check the .Net source and see how many lines of code are behind each get).

Therefore I would recommend you to have your own structure of meshes with Lists (List, List) for Positions and TriangleIndices. In my observations, Lists of structs are faster than using simple arrays of structs (but the lists must be presized - their size need to be set in constructor). This way you can access the data much faster. Also, when an extra boost is needed, you may also use unsafe blocks with pointers. You may also add some other data to your mesh classes - for example you mentioned adjacent edges.

Once you have your positions and triangle indices set, you can create the WPF's MeshGeometry3D object with the following code:

```
var wpfMesh = new MeshGeometry3D()
{
    Positions = new Point3DCollection(optimizedPositions),
    TriangleIndices = new Int32Collection(optimizedTriangleIndices)
};
```

This is faster than adding each Point3D to Positions collection.

Because you will not change that instance of wpfMesh (for each change you will create a new MeshGeometry3D), you can freeze it - call Freeze() on it. This allows WPF to optimize the meshes (combine them into vertex buffers) to reduce the number of draw calls. What is more, after you freeze a MeshGeometry3D (or any other WPF object), you can pass it from one thread to another. This means that you can parallelize your work and create the MeshGeometry3D objects in worker threads and then pass them to UI thread as frozen objects.

The same applies to change the Positions (and other data) in MeshGeometry3D object. It is faster to copy the existing positions to an array or List, change the data there and then recreate the Positions collection back from your array, then to change each individual position. Before doing any change of MeshGeometry3D you also need to disconnect it from the parent GeometryModel3D to prevent triggering many change events. This is done with the following:

```
 var mesh = parentGeometryModel3D.Geometry; // Save MeshGeometry3D to mesh 
 parentGeometryModel3D.Geometry = null; // Disconnect

 // modify the mesh here ...

 parentGeometryModel3D.Geometry = mesh; // Connect the mesh back
```